# PHP SQL redirect form after random amount of sentences displayed from database

Tags: php, sql

I have a form which retrieves 10 random sentences from the  database.

```
// --- retrieve a new sentence
$sql = "SELECT sentence FROM Sentence
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 10";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

$sentence = $row["sentence"];

// --- display sentence
echo "<p>\n";
print $sentence;
echo "</p>\n";

echo "</div>\n";
```

The form displays one sentence at a time.  The user checks a radio button, clicks the next button, a new sentence appears.

However, once the 10 sentences have been displayed, it keeps looping and I want it to redirect to a new page after those 10 have been.

I'm currently trying this method:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["count"]) {
      if ($_SESSION["count"] < 10) {
          $sql = "SELECT sentence FROM Sentence
          ORDER BY RAND() 
          LIMIT 10";

         $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

          $sentence = $row["sentence"];

          echo "<p>\n";
          print $sentence;
          echo "</p>\n";

         //increment counter
         $_SESSION["count"] = $_SESSION["count"] + 1;
    } else {
         header("Location: newurl");
     }
    } else {
       $_SESSION["count"] = 0;
    }
```

However I'm receiving the error Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: you're **NOT** receiving that error? Because if you are, there's literally thousands of q&a on this site with that exact error. Otherwise... where's `session_start()`? Without that, your session code is useless.

Comment: Why are you selecting 10 sentences when you are only displaying 1?  I think maybe you aren't showing us some code.  Is there javascript or something else at play here that allows you put put 10 sentences into the DOM and then display them one at a time?

Comment: @MarcB the session start is right at the top of my php file

Comment: @MikeBrant I do have javascript in this file however it doesn't affect the selection of the sentences.

It should be a session of 10, 1 displayed each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment printing code for testing:

```
if (isset($_SESSION["count"]) {
  if ($_SESSION["count"] < 10) {
      $sql = "SELECT sentence FROM Sentence
      ORDER BY RAND() 
      LIMIT 10";

     $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);

      $sentence = $row["sentence"];

      //echo "<p>\n";
      //print $sentence;
      //echo "</p>\n";

     //increment counter
     $_SESSION["count"] = $_SESSION["count"] + 1;
} else {
     header("Location: newurl");
 }
} else {
   $_SESSION["count"] = 0;
}
```

Is redirect work?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems:

- You are not iterating through the result array correctly. Since you are limiting the result to 10 rows, you have to assume that you are receiving 10 rows.

Use a while loop to iterate throgh all rows:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
$sentence = $row["sentence"];

// --- display sentence
echo "<p>\n";
print $sentence . '<br>';
echo "</p>\n";
}
```

- The error that you are getting is caused because you are not calling
  session_start(). The call to session_start() needs to be the first
  line in your script otherwise you will get the same error.

Also replace

```
if (isset($_SESSION["count"])
```

with

```
if ( isset($_SESSION["count"]) )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Now I have all 10 sentences in one long paragraph.

Comment: You have to add <br> at end of each row. Look at my revised answer.

Comment: Did that resolve your problem? please mark the correct answer so we all become wiser.

Comment: No, still receiving the Warning: Cannot modify header information error. my session start is the first line too.

Comment: your first if statement is missing a closing bracket. Should be if ( isset($_SESSION["count"]) ). Could be causing the problem.

Comment: at this point, I'd suggest revising your question. You're probably not giving us all information and only part of the code. Your original question is actually 2 different problems - so I don't even know what your current error is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_SESSION["count"]) {
      if ($_SESSION["count"] < 10) {
          $sql = "SELECT sentence FROM Sentence
          ORDER BY RAND() 
          LIMIT 10";

         $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

          $sentence = $row["sentence"];

          echo "<p>\n";
          echo $sentence;
          echo "</p>\n";


      }

         //increment counter
         $_SESSION["count"] = $_SESSION["count"] + 1;
    } else {
         header("Location: newurl");
     }
    } else {
       $_SESSION["count"] = 0;
    }
```

That should do it.

Comment: this again is displaying all 10 sentences combined into one large paragraph

Comment: Then you have to put <br /> on the end of the while loop.